# Woocommerce - store all products of a specific attribute in an array

Tags: filter, attributes, woocommerce

With this code I can get the value of the current product attribute:

```
$terms = get_the_terms( $product->id, 'pa_myAttribute');
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
   echo $term->name;
}
```

I don't know how to get all products with this attribute and store their ids in an array.

Answer (score 0):

Knowing that an attribute is merely a custom taxonomy you can use [`WP_Query`'s taxonomy parameters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters) to run a quick [`get_posts()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) to return an array of posts that have a particular term in the desired attribute taxonomy. Finally you can use [`wp_list_pluck()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pluck) to quickly convert that to an array of only the post IDs.

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'product',
                'tax_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'pa_color',
                        'field'    => 'slug',
                        'terms'    => 'blue',
                    )
                )
            );

$posts = get_posts( $args );
$post_ids = wp_list_pluck( $posts, 'ID' );
```

In the above example, the `get_posts()` will return all products that have been assigned the blue term in the color attribute.

Comment: I tried the code and apparently the `wp_list_pluck ` function gave me some weird complete info. I manipulated the code and this worked: `$posts = get_posts( $args ); // gives u products $post_ids = wp_list_pluck( $posts ); // gives you products with more info foreach ( $posts as $post ) { echo $post->ID;  }`

Comment: Forgot the second parameter in `wp_list_pluck()`, so try that one more time now that I've edited it.